# Right triangle inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry

Please help me on this problem.

> Points $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are on sides $AB$, $CD$, and $BC$ of rectangle $\square ABCD$ as shown below, such that $|BP|=4$, $|CQ|=18$, $\angle PRQ=90^\circ$, and $|CR|=2|BR|$. Find $|PQ|$.

[image]

Comment: Use pythagorean theorem and simple algebra with variables. $[4^2 + b^2]+[18^2 +4b^2]=PQ^2=9b^2+(18-4)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we need to calculate the length of BR and RC.

We notice that $\triangle BPR $ and $\triangle CRQ$ are similar.

(Proof of similar triangles:

$\angle CRQ+\angle CQR=90^{\circ}$, and $\angle CRQ+\angle BRP=90^{\circ}$, so $\angle CQR=\angle BRP$. Also, $\angle PBR=\angle RCQ=90^{\circ}$. Having these two pairs of equal angles, we can prove  $\triangle BPR $ and $\triangle CRQ$ are similar.)

Since $\triangle BPR $ and $\triangle CRQ$ are similar, we have $\frac{|RC|}{|BP|}=\frac{|CQ|}{|BR|} \Rightarrow \frac{2*|BR|}{4}=\frac{18}{|BR|}\Rightarrow 2*|BR|^2=72\Rightarrow |BR|=6$

Next, by Pythagorean theorem, we have

$|BR|^2+|BP|^2=|PR^2|\Rightarrow4^2+6^2=|PR|^2\Rightarrow |PR|=\sqrt{52}$

$|RC|^2+|CQ|^2=|RQ^2| \Rightarrow 12^2+18^2=|RQ|^2\Rightarrow |RQ|=\sqrt{468}$,

and $|PR|^2+|RQ|^2=|PQ|^2 \Rightarrow 52+468=|PQ|^2 \Rightarrow |PQ|=\sqrt{520}$

Hope that helps!